# Azure Logic App Office 365 mail connector new mail trigger does not work with alternate credentials

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I've tried to do a simple azure logic app. I'm using the office 365 connector and an email trigger of "When_a_new_email_arrives" (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook/#when-a-new-email-arrives). It seems to work if I send an email to the target account, push the trigger. At least when matched between azure login & office 365 mailbox (i.e. both uses the same id xxx@company.com)

However, if the mailbox belongs to another user say yyy@company.com it doesn't seem to work even though it is "authorized". The trigger always comes back as 'skipped'. I think I'm getting to the correct mailbox because if I say a different source folder that does not exist in the target mailbox I do get an error.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is the mailbox of the other user (yyy@company.com) an Office 365 hosted mailbox?

Comment: Yes. All office 365 mailboxes. In fact in this case all within the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I walked away from this and tried it again and it worked straight away. So, I believe this was a bug, as it now works with only me doing an "authorize" again (something I had previously done).

The answer that it can't be done is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can only work with one account with the Office 365 Connector Api. 
The only account you can use is the one you logged in with.

Comment: where is this documented? It does seem that the infrastructure is all there and in fact if I tell the connector to look at a folder that does not exist in the other mailbox it does give me an error, so it definitely has the ability to look at the other mailbox.

Comment: When you configure the Connector, you are prompted to sign in using your Office 365 credentials.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook/

In order to access another account, you would need to pass in the User Id and Password.  That functionality does not exist in the current version of the connector.